# Using CSS to Target Text That Has No Container

Tags: html, css, text

I'm not sure if this is possible but it would help immensely if it is. I'm working on an e-commerce site in the Volusion framework and a lot of text is dynamically generated on Volusion sites. Most of the text is in `<span>`s or `<div>`s as normal but every once in a while there is a ":" that is displayed after a category header. You can see it in the below code that I grabbed from a page I'm working on:

```
<td>
<span class="PageText_L71n">Qty</span>:
<input type="text" class="v65-productdetail-cartqty" name="QTY.WA-SSPURSE" size="3" maxlength="8" onkeydown="javascript:QtyEnabledAddToCart();" value="1">
</td>
```

You can see the colon after the `</span>` that is just being displayed but not in any container. Is there any way to target that? I'm trying to put a `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` on it since I'm doing quite a bit of custom coding and it's just hanging there right now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: CSS cannot select text nodes.  However, that is contained by the `<td>`.  You can either use that to your advantage or use JavaScript

Comment: @ExplosionPills, ah ok yeah I just had the idea of setting the text color in the td to 'white' since the background on the site is white and then setting the span text color to be black with an '!important' so it overrides it. That may work. Sometimes it just takes someone to say something!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the container of the colon ahead of time, you can change the font color to match the background or use `font-size: 0` (which I like because it also removes unnecessary space):

```
td {
    font-size: 0;
}
td * {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Obviously adjust for specifics that work for your site in particular.

Answer (score -1):

If all the elements in the td are known, then target all of them with the :after and :before pseudo selectors.

```
td span:after {
    content:"<span class="hide">"; }
td input:before {
    content:"</span>"; }
.hide {
    display:none; }
```

I have not tested this nor ever used these selectors but it should work.

If there are multiple elements of the same kind, say three inputs you can use the nth-child selector on td.

Comment: I just looked into this and found that it inserts plain text only. HTML will not render. Dumb. :(

Comment: If it was possible to insert HTML with CSS, would be no reason to have HTML, all could be done with CSS.

Comment: @Max There was a time when we didn't have css at all, so the opposite argument could be made. The idea that css can be used to create content,  as these selectors do, is frankly a breach of the original intent. It's debatable that repetitious content, the primary use of these selectors, is style, and not just content. I've thought a lot about this topic since I made this answer 5 and a half years ago.

Comment: @Max You can also make every tag except the html tag with JavaScript. There's plenty of reasons to argue these selectors should not add tags, but "then we wouldn't need html" is not a good one.

Comment: What i am saying is CSS shouldn't mess with HTML (content) but with style. Currently, `:before` and `:after`are really handfull and would be nice to add more elements via CSS with other pseudo-selectors. But those elements shouldn't affect the content (eg: insert article content via css or elements with custom classes). They should only set style (diagonal bars, custom loaders, etc). Currently, if i want to make an loader with 4 floating balls i need unless 2 HTML elements or great CSS hacks. In that point i agree that CSS should be more powerfull.